# Why isn't session nil?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
def page_main
    @temp = ""
    if session[:session_id] != nil
        @temp = Mymodel.find(session[:session_id]).user_id
    end
end
```

I don't have any action about session before this code.
So, I would think the session must be nil.
But, when I run this code, there is an error.

```
Couldn't find Mymodel with 'id'=551d118f13497d19696cc4db615dc500
```

This means the session[:session_id] is 551d118f13497d19696cc4db615dc500?
What's wrong?

Comment: Session is created every time new user visits your website, not only when he signs in

Comment: You should make the comment an answer!